# Starting Rails with heroku-buildpack-multi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to use the [subject software](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) as part of loading tesseract on Heroku, but Rails is not starting up. I've taken out the non-ruby stuff so that the `.buildpacks` file just has the following line in it:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

but Rails will still not start up automatically. I have to execute `heroku ps:scale web=1` to get things going. Any idea what I can do to get Rails to start automatically in this context?

Update: After adding the following line to my `.buildpacks` and pushing again:

```
https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries
```

The file `.buildpacks_bin_download` contains:

```
tesseract-ocr https://s3.amazonaws.com/tesseract-ocr/heroku/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz 3.02 eng,spa
```

the Rails server is no longer running. When I do `heroku ps`, nothing shows. When I do `heroku ps:scale web=1` I get the following:

```
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Here's the tail of the logs file. Note that I did `heroku run bash` a couple of times during this:

```
2013-11-18T04:04:38.184151+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by palfvin@gmail.com
2013-11-18T04:04:43.267609+00:00 heroku[run.5246]: Awaiting client
2013-11-18T04:04:43.330445+00:00 heroku[run.5246]: Starting process with command `bash`
2013-11-18T04:04:43.385663+00:00 heroku[run.5246]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-18T04:05:05.124216+00:00 heroku[run.5246]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-18T04:05:05.142063+00:00 heroku[run.5246]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-18T04:09:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-18T04:10:30.590354+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9dc41c1 by palfvin@gmail.com
2013-11-18T04:10:30.627601+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v24 created by palfvin@gmail.com
2013-11-18T04:10:30+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-18T04:12:29.331142+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by palfvin@gmail.com
2013-11-18T04:12:36.325595+00:00 heroku[run.9509]: Awaiting client
2013-11-18T04:12:36.371452+00:00 heroku[run.9509]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-18T04:12:36.385073+00:00 heroku[run.9509]: Starting process with command `bash`
2013-11-18T04:12:46.408695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=avlats.herokuapp.com fwd="71.189.7.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-18T04:12:45.889685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=avlats.herokuapp.com fwd="71.189.7.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-18T04:13:23.728990+00:00 heroku[run.9509]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-18T04:13:23.714522+00:00 heroku[run.9509]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-18T04:33:20.414300+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by palfvin@gmail.com
2013-11-18T04:33:27.248649+00:00 heroku[run.8551]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-18T04:33:27.326433+00:00 heroku[run.8551]: Awaiting client
2013-11-18T04:33:27.387998+00:00 heroku[run.8551]: Starting process with command `bash`
2013-11-18T04:35:43.706884+00:00 heroku[run.8551]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-18T04:35:43.719152+00:00 heroku[run.8551]: State changed from up to complete
```

Here's the output from my `git push heroku` after changing the order in `.buildpacks` so that the ruby line comes second:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 293 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/marcolinux/heroku-buildpack-libraries
=====> Detected Framework: detect
Adding library tesseract-ocr
Downloading Binaries
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9224k  100 9224k    0     0  2313k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 2326k
Building runtime environment for tesseract-ocr
customizing tesseract-ocr
3.02
/tmp/build_f35a94fc-d088-4c7a-8731-65e170fb67ae/vendor/
Getting tesseract-ocr training data
English training data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.0M  100 12.0M    0     0  3277k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 3369k
eng training data
https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.0M  100 12.0M    0     0  11.4M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.0M
spa training data
https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.spa.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9613k  100 9613k    0     0  8781k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 9243k
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using Ascii85 (1.0.2)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.2)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using activesupport (4.0.1)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.1)
       Using mime-types (1.25)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.1)
       Using activemodel (4.0.1)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using activerecord (4.0.1)
       Using afm (0.2.0)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.1)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using hashery (2.1.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
       Using ttfunk (1.0.3)
       Using pdf-reader (1.3.3)
       Using pg (0.17.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using rails (4.0.1)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.12)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
       Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
       Using uglifier (2.3.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.49s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (2.11s)
       Cleaning assets
-----> WARNINGS:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
       Using release configuration from last framework Ruby:
       --- 
       addons: 
       - heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
       default_process_types: 
         rake: bundle exec rake
         console: bin/rails console
         web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
         worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for Multipack -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 66.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v25
       http://avlats.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: So I don't see any sign of a web process coming up in that log, nor does it look like the Ruby buildpack is being added at all.  Can you post the output from your `git push heroku master` when you revert your .buildpacks file to contain just the heroku-buildpack-ruby line?  That output typically lists the process types available for scaling.

Comment: And you should review the discussion of Procfiles here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile .  A Heroku app deployed on a Cedar platform should have a Procfile (it's not strictly required, but its a good idea).

Comment: What does the Heroku web console look like when you put the Ruby line second?  It looks like the web process type should be available.  When you tail the logs, do you see the web process starting up?

Comment: Ok, when I added the `Procfile`, it changed the output from the git push that showed the web process being launched, but there was no dyno available. However, when I did the `heroku ps:scale web=1` it "took" and everything is working now. So, I guess the `Procfile` becomes significant when using the multi-buildbacks approach.

Comment: So with the Procfile you're all good?  Everything running?

Comment: Yeah, the combination of the `Procfile` and the `heroku ps:scale web=1` took care of it. Hopefully, I won't have to do that command on each push.

Comment: You shouldn't.  As as said above, you should just have to scale it up once.

Comment: Unfortunately, the marcolinux repos on github seem to be gone...

Comment: @Erik have you found an alternative?

Comment: @LeoRomanovsky yep, try this: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Answer (score 1):

A Rails app won't run on Heroku unless you've got a running web dyno.  That's all your `heroku ps:scale web=1` command is doing - starting a single web dyno.

Heroku is a PaaS solution that requires you to set up resources, including the dynos on which your app will run.  Once you've scaled to a non-zero number of web dynos you shouldn't need to do it again - the web dynos will stay active and will be updated with subsequent pushes to Heroku.  If the dyno should crash for any reason Heroku will start another one to keep the number of running dynos as you've configured it.

So if you need one and only one dyno, you should be fine going forward.  If you need to scale your app up and down in response to load, you will need to address that.

Comment: I've never had to execute that command before in order to spin up the initial dyno. Any idea why it's required in this context?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I'm not sure why you didn't need to execute that command or spin up a dyno via the web console before - I've always had to spin up my initial dynos of each type.

Comment: Regarding your update, do you have a .buildpacks_bin_build file in place?

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but when I got to my Heroku dashboard for this app now, there's no information provided for the `Dyno` section (e.g. no way to change the # dynos).

Comment: Well that's just plain weird.  Anything odd in your Procfile?  When you deploy does it tell you which dyno types it is supporting? - that's typically a line in the deploy

Comment: I don't have a `Procfile` that I can see. And I'm not sure what you mean by "it tells you" in the context of a deploy. I'll post the tail of the logs.